# Create beans depends on spring profile

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-bean

I have strange problem.
Create beans depends on spring profile. Create annotation and use it on bean class.
Anntoations:

```
@Profile("dev")
public @interface Dev {
}

@Profile("prod")
public @interface Prod {
}
```

using:

```
public interface Facade {
    String test();
}

@Dev
@Component("facade")
public class DevFacade implements Facade {
    public String test() {
        return "Dev";
    }
}

@Prod
@Component("facade")
public class ProdFacade implements Facade{
    public String test() {
        return "Prod";
    }
}
```

Until spring boot version 2.1.18.RELEASE it works fine. When I set `spring.profiles.active=dev` I will get only bean `DevFacade`. But above version 2.2.0.RELEASE It doesn't work and I get
`Caused by: org.springframework.context.annotation.ConflictingBeanDefinitionException: Annotation-specified bean name 'facade' for bean class [com.example.demo.test.ProdFacade] conflicts with existing, non-compatible bean definition of same name and class [com.example.demo.test.DevFacade]`. This means Spring create both beans for dev and prod profile, but why?
When I modify classes and use `@Profile("dev")` instead of `@Dev` it works.

Have someone any idea why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User Retention annotation. @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Profile("dev")
  public @interface Dev {
}

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Profile("prod")
  public @interface Prod {
}
```

Comment: That's routine :(
You have right. I forgot about retention